# How to schedule database backup?

Tags: cron, backup, scheduled-tasks, whenever

I used the backup gem to make a backup of my database. (not so important here)
I want to schedule that on every minute (to test it for the beginning).

schedule.rb file:

```
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"
every 1.minute do
    command "backup perform -t expense_backup"
end
```

At first I tried this in the backup Backup/config folder. I moved this into the schedule.rb of my app where I already have a scheduled task which works fine. There is also no output in cron_log file. The output of the whenever command for this task is this:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'backup perform -t expense_backup >> log/cron_log.log 2>&1'
```

EDIT:
   if I write system insted of command and then try whenever, it performs the backup! The problem is that it doesn't trigger the task every minute.

Answer (score 1):

Most of troubles with things like "it works in my console but not with my cron job" are about variable environments like PATH. You should use absolute path to launch your script or be sure that it's in the PATH used by cron.

Comment: It works now. whenever and than
whenever --update-crontab. Otherwise, it doesn't work for me. Actualy, I'm pretty sure I've tried even this at the beginning, but I won't complain now.